# Determine the length of a side of an octahedron from the volume

Tags: geometry, platonic-solids

I am looking for a formula that can convert the volume of an octahedron to the length of an edge. So far, I have come across $\frac{1.442\cdot3\sqrt{v}}{1.122}$, but I am not sure if this equation is accurate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron#Area_and_volume) to the rescue.

Comment: I suspect that was supposed to be $\sqrt[3]v$, not $3\sqrt v$. But why $1.442/1.122$? Why not either give it as one decimal, or show its exact value (using a square root symbol)? You could edit the question to say where that value came from. (Do you have a link to a web page?)

Comment: No, sorry. I forgot where i got it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, that octahedron is dual to cube.

The volume of octahedron inscribed in cube is equal to $\frac{1}{6}$ volume of cube, ie:
$$v_o = \frac{1}{6}v_c$$
And the length of a side of octahedron is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ side of cube, ie:
$$l_o = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}l_c$$
Length of side of cube is equal to cubic root of it's volume:
$$l_c = \sqrt[3]{v_c}$$

Then we have:
$$l_o = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt[3]{6v_o}$$

Comment: Nice neat derviation.